# QML : How to get current item in Pathview

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I would like to know how to get the current item in the Pathview.

We do have have iscurrentItem property but how can we use it if its possible. With my present implementation I'm getting the current index but not the value of the item at that index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the **preferredHighlightBegin** and **preferredHighlightEnd** properties defined you could use the **childAt** function to get the current item:

```
//example for vertical path
view.childAt(0, view.height * (preferredHighlightEnd + preferredHighlightBegin) / 2.0);
```

There is another approach where you can iterate all the children of the PathView and find which of the children is the current item:

```
for(var i = 0; i < view.children.length; ++i)
{
  if(view.children[i].PathView.isCurrentItem){
    console.log(i + " is current item")
    //view.children[i] is your current item here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your delegate Item you can set a Connection that updates a path custom property:

```
PathView {
  id: myPathView

  // ...

  property Item currentItem
  delegate: pathDelegate
}

Component {
  id: pathDelegate

  Item {
    id: delegateItem

    // ...

    Connection {
      target: myPathView
      onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        if (myPathView.currentIndex === delegateItem.index) {
          myPathView.currentItem = delegateItem;
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Not so efficient, but it works.